# Code Issue: Handling Rapid Clicks and Game Initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently grappling with a coding challenge and could really use some assistance. I've encountered an issue with a specific code snippet I'm working on. The problem I'm facing occurs when I rapidly click the first time. During this initial click, the code behaves incorrectly. However, interestingly, it starts to handle rapid clicks correctly after this initial hiccup. Despite my efforts to troubleshoot, I've been unable to resolve the problem, and I'm looking for guidance.

---

```
var gameStatus= "game";
var isGameStillRunning= false;
var isGameBusy= false;

$(".cube").on("click", function() {

    if (isGameBusy) {
        console.log("game is busy")
        return;
    }
    console.log("isGameBusy "+isGameBusy)
    if (gameStatus == "game" && !isGameBusy) {
        isGameBusy= true;
        
        console.log("isGameBusy "+isGameBusy)

        setTimeout(() => {
            gameSequence_filler();
            console.log(gameSequence);
            $("#game_text").html("Level " + level);
            gameSequence_Executer ();
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout (function () {
            isGameBusy= false;
          }, gameSequence_Executer_Delay*gameSequence.length*1000+100);
    }
    else if (gameStatus== "player") {
            playerSequence_filler(this);
    }
});
```

Here are some details about the issue:

1. Rapid Clicks: The problem primarily manifests when I spam a series of rapid clicks during the first interaction with the code. It seems that the code isn't reacting as expected during this initial phase.
2. Troubleshooting Efforts: I've invested a considerable amount of time attempting to troubleshoot the issue. I've reviewed my code, checked event handling, and inspected the initialization process, but my efforts have been in vain thus far also tried to figure it with chatgpt but couldn't figure it out.
3. Possible Solution: One potential solution I'm considering is shifting the entire game's start from the first click to the second. While this may serve as a workaround, I believe it's crucial to address the root cause of the problem.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or tips that the community can offer to help me resolve this issue. If you require additional details about the code or specific sections of the code snippet, please let me know, and I'll provide them promptly.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You have not given us a [mre], so we aren't able to reproduce, understand, and fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `isGameBusy` is intitally `false` so it goes through the guarding `if` that returns if game is busy. On your first click that means you are setting it to `true` if `gameStatus == "game"`. Then you set a first timeout to appear after some time `gameSequence_Executer_Delay*gameSequence.length*1000+100` which sets it to `false` so that your guarding `if` doesn't stop your code from executing.

Your problem seems to arise from this circumstance. I don't know when `gameStatus == "game"` and `gameStatus == "player"` is truthy but this would also play a role for sure form what you have given. The only way `isGameBusy` is set to true is if `!isGameBusy` and `gameStatus == "game"` and then to set it to false it only happens after the `gameSequence_Executer_Delay*gameSequence.length*1000+100` delay which could be the delay you experience on the first click as you say.

From what you have given so far though that is the extension to what I can help you with, I hope you will figure out the rest.

Also your `if (gameStatus == "game" && !isGameBusy)` is redundant because of the guarding `if (isGameBusy) { return; }` prior to that and can be written as just `if (gameStatus == "game")`

Comment: thank you for the assistance. I've figured the problem out. Someone on Reddit told me that there are multiple. Multiplications in the delay and one of them might be initially set to 0. Yes, this was true, and the solution was pretty simple. I just added this `(gameSequence.length > 0? gameSequence.length : 1)`

Comment: @KareemA well I am happy you got it resolved. I guess you posted more info on reddit so people know what your code actually does with those unknown variables

Comment: Thank you. No, I copied and pasted the whole thing into Reddit, if you wish you can check the reddit here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/16cudlz/code_issue_handling_rapid_clicks_and_game/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the "gameSequence.length" was initially set to zero, so the delay time was simply zero. the solution is pretty straightforward by adding ternary operator to replace "gameSequence.length" with "1" if it equals to zero `gameSequence_Executer_Delay*(gameSequence.length > 0? gameSequence.length : 1)*1000+100` the old one `gameSequence_Executer_Delay*gameSequence.length*1000+100`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).